# Intel SST Audio Device WDM” not working on Pop OS 20.04 and other Ubuntu based distros

Tags: drivers, audio, intel, microphone

I have no sound in the Pop OS 20.04 or any other distro I tested. In windows the card and audio drivers work perfectly. Audio and microphone.

I can't find specific instructions to solve that problem in internet.

I've found some commands that bring me the information below wich might help, still I have no idea of what to do.

Tanks a lot

```
danilomataveli@pop-os:~$ lsmod | grep "sst"
snd_soc_sst_bytcr_rt5640    40960  0
snd_intel_sst_acpi     20480  1
snd_intel_sst_core     61440  1 snd_intel_sst_acpi
snd_soc_sst_atom_hifi2_platform   110592  1 snd_intel_sst_core
snd_soc_rt5640        143360  1 snd_soc_sst_bytcr_rt5640
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match    32768  2 snd_sof_acpi,snd_intel_sst_acpi
snd_soc_acpi           16384  4 snd_soc_sst_bytcr_rt5640,snd_sof_acpi,snd_soc_acpi_intel_match,snd_intel_sst_acpi
snd_soc_core          245760  7 snd_soc_rt5651,snd_soc_sst_bytcr_rt5640,snd_sof,snd_soc_rt5670,snd_soc_rt5640,snd_soc_sst_atom_hifi2_platform,snd_soc_rt5645
snd_pcm               106496  10 snd_soc_rt5651,snd_soc_sst_bytcr_rt5640,snd_sof,snd_soc_rt5670,snd_soc_rt5640,snd_hdmi_lpe_audio,snd_soc_sst_atom_hifi2_platform,snd_soc_core,snd_soc_rt5645,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd                    90112  12 snd_seq,snd_soc_sst_bytcr_rt5640,snd_seq_device,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_hdmi_lpe_audio,snd_soc_sst_atom_hifi2_platform,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi

danilomataveli@pop-os:~$ dmesg | grep "sst"
[    8.742713] intel_sst_acpi 808622A8:00: LPE base: 0x91400000 size:0x200000
[    8.742718] intel_sst_acpi 808622A8:00: IRAM base: 0x914c0000
[    8.742763] intel_sst_acpi 808622A8:00: DRAM base: 0x91500000
[    8.742775] intel_sst_acpi 808622A8:00: SHIM base: 0x91540000
[    8.742787] intel_sst_acpi 808622A8:00: Mailbox base: 0x91544000
[    8.742796] intel_sst_acpi 808622A8:00: DDR base: 0x20000000
[    8.743076] intel_sst_acpi 808622A8:00: Got drv data max stream 25

danilomataveli@pop-os:~$ ls /sys/class/sound
card0  controlC0  pcmC0D0p  pcmC0D1p  pcmC0D2p  seq  timer
```